# Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas where column value in list

Tags: python, pandas

How to remove certain rows in Pandas dataframe where column value is in list? For example:

```
given mylist = [fh3, fh1, fh4]

   id  loc_id
0  fh0  0859
1  fh1  5861
2  fh2  2585
3  fh3  853
4  fh4  45596
4  fh5  586

remove rows where id in mylist:

   id  loc_id
0  fh0  0859
2  fh2  2585
4  fh5  586
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mylist = ['fh3', 'fh1', 'fh4']
print (df[~df.id.isin(mylist)])
    id  loc_id
0  fh0     859
2  fh2    2585
4  fh5     586
```

Another solution with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
mylist = ['fh3', 'fh1', 'fh4']
print (df.set_index('id').drop(mylist).reset_index())
    id  loc_id
0  fh0     859
1  fh2    2585
2  fh5     586
```